# Context help in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, helpfile

Is there a way to change the context sensitive help in Visual Studio so that it will only search against the text under the caret instead of a compilation error in your code?

More info:
After you compile and receive a compilation error(underlined), placing the caret within the underlined text and pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> will take you to the Compilation error page instead of the help for the function under the caret.
Can this behavior be changed to always go to the method/keyword help?

Language: C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to fix the compile error ;-)

A workaround is to **use the 'Dynamic Help' window** (from the help menu, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>), the compile error is top of the list but the usual item will be listed next.

For those that don't understand the question, here's a trivial, unrealistic example:

```
int myInt = new int(3);
```

As soon as you move off the line, the 'new int(3);' bit is underlined in red, but if you select the second 'int' and press <kbd>F1</kbd>, you get help on declaring integers.

However if you compile it, the offending section is underlined with a wiggly blue line and selecting 'int' and pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> takes you to help on the compile error. It's not just a case of the focus moving to the Error List window.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember, after you compile, the default selected window is the message (error list) one.  If you hit <kbd>F1</kbd> at this point, you will get help on the error message.  But if you select the code window, you will get the help on the selected text.

Is this the behavior your are experiencing???